# Artifactory jenkins Integration using gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I managed to publish my artifacts by using Gradle into Artifactory.
But the version is always unspecified (example-unspecified.jar)

How Can set groupId ="com.example" and version 'BUILD_NUMBER' into jenkins??

I want to publish something like that
example-10.jar (10 is Jenkins build number, and group: 'com.example')

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `group` and `version` in the `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "java"

group = 'com.company.blah'
version = project.hasProperty('build_number') ? project.properties['build_number'] : '0.1'
```

Then the build will produce artifacts like `"$project.name-${project.version}.jar"`

The `group` is used by maven to organize the artifacts and is the first item in dependency notation `"$project.group:$project.name:$project.version"`

So if we build without any params it will produce `blah-0.1.jar`
If we build with the param `build_number` it will assign the version supplied.

For example: `gradlew clean build -Pbuild_number=10` will produce `blah-10.jar`

Comment: Thanks. How can I make a version number = BUILD_NUMBER??

Comment: Updated.  We need to pass it from jenkins to the gradle build.  From jenkins it would look like `./gradlew clean build -Pbuild_number=$BUILD_NUMBER`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Is this something it can be added in the artifactory plugin code?:

I have: buildInfo = rtGradle.run rootDir: "/dev-test", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 'clean artifactoryPublish'  And I don´t see anywere that : "-Pbuild_number=$BUILD_NUMBER" can be added there

Answer (score 1):

`BUILD_NUMBER` is populated via environment variables by Jenkins. If you want to get access to it from Gradle script, you can do it as follows:

```
def buildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER")
```

And then use `buildNumber` variable in your artifactory publish code.

As for `groupId`, I don't really understand what's the problem there.. It doesn't change during Jenkins build, does it? So you can just hardcode it inside your gradle script.

As an alternative, you can pass necessary information via project properties:

```
./gradlew assemble -PgroupId=com.example -PbuildNumber=$BUILD_NUMBER
```